# How do i fix the indents in my html/php files in vim?

Tags: php, html, vim

I am (slowly) making the switch to vim. I have added some settings to my .vimrc file (:syntax enable, :fileype plugin on, autoindent, etc.). Everything works great except when I try to indent lines using >. It double indents:

<div>
----<p>this line was autoindented </p>
</div>

<div>
--------<p>this line was indented using the > key </p>
</div>

I am a bit of a vim noob. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question means that `>` applied to the line without indentation, adds 8 spaces to the line start?

Comment: Yes it was. Fixed now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both of the following are set in your .vimrc file

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set tabstop *and* shiftwidth to the desired size - add this to your .vimrc:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

You can read up about it on the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Indenting_source_code).

If you don't have `expandtab` set, add that too - it converts tabs to spaces.  If you have a file that has mixed tabs and spaces, `:retab` will go through and convert everything to your current settings as well.

Your example seems odd, because autoindent *should*, as far as I know, take its setting from `shiftwidth` - so they should be the same.  You are indenting the single line with >>, correct?

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about expandtab and :retab. And to answer your question - I am now. Thanks!